# Main class is not being found when I run my project on eclipse neon

Tags: java, main-method

I am trying to run my project, but the main class isn't being found. Whats wrong? Here's my code.

```
public class ArrayPrinter {
    public static void printArray(int[] arr) {
    int size = arr.length;
System.out.print("[");
    for(int i=0;i< size; i++){
        System.out.print(arr[i]);
           if(i<size-1){
         System.out.print(",");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("]");
}

}
```

Comment: there is no main class

Comment: So how do I give it one, sorry i have trouble with this @aleksv

Comment: A main class has a `public static void main(String[] args)` method .

Comment: So does that go on top @Berger

Comment: Please before doing anything else, consider going through a Java tutorial or introductory book. These questions suggests that you're trying to code without doing this most necessary first step, and continuing this way will only frustrate you.

Comment: Java and Javascript are completely different languages, don't specify both tags unless you are asking about both languages.

Comment: You even tagged the question `main-method`. It's a **method**. Called **`main`**. Like your first "Hello World" program had. If you haven't done a ["Hello World" program](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/), go back to chapter 1 of you Java guide and read it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of the main function always looks the same:

```
 public class ArrayPrinter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       // put code here
    }

    public static void printArray(int[] arr) {
    int size = arr.length;
System.out.print("[");
    for(int i=0;i< size; i++){
        System.out.print(arr[i]);
           if(i<size-1){
         System.out.print(",");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("]");
}

}
```

Comment: If you are using eclipse you can press CTRL+space anywhere outside of the methods of your class and it will suggest creating a main method.

Answer (score 2):

You need a main *method*, not class. See below:

```
public class ArrayPrinter {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Sample use
        int[] arr = new int[2];
        arr[0] = 4;
        arr[1] = 2;
        printArray(arr);
    }

    public static void printArray(int[] arr) {
        int size = arr.length;
        System.out.print("[");
        for(int i = 0;i < size; i++){
            System.out.print(arr[i]);
            if (i < size-1){
                System.out.print(",");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("]");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a `main` method in order to run a Java application.

The signature of the main method is

`public static void main (String[] args)`

More info can be found
[here](https://csis.pace.edu/~bergin/KarelJava2ed/ch2/javamain.html)